# How to reinitialize the website in Application.cfm file scope

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfm

Maybe the Title seems bit odd, but my question is straight, how can reinitialize the application with Application.cfm, i know how we do in Application.cfc like

```
<cfscript>
if(structKeyExists(url, 'reinit')) {
    onApplicationStart();
}
</cfscript>
```

But how in Application.cfm, not sure, please guide

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, running `onApplicationStart()` no more restarts the application than running an `onClick()` mouse-click event handler causes your mouse button to depress. `onApplicationStart()` is called *as a result* of the application starting, not the other way around.

Secondly, Application.cfm has nothing to do with the application lifecycle, it is merely a CFML file that is included at the beginning of every *request*. it is more closely associated with `onRequestStart()` than `onApplicationStart()`: the file is, unfortunately, misnamed. Its counterpart `onRequestEnd.cfm` demonstrates this.

I presume your requirement here is to re-initialise your application scope, yes? Do you have all your application-scope setting isolated in a specific CFML file, eg: `applicationSettings.cfm`, and then have logic like this in your `Application.cfm`:

```
// Application.cfm
if (!structKeyExists(application, "inited")){
    include "applicationSettings.cfm";
}
```

(then as a last thing in `applicationSettings.cfm` set `application.inited` to `true`).

If so you simply need to modify your condition to include your URL reinit variable, eg:

```
if (!structKeyExists(application, "inited") || structKeyExists(URL, "reinit")){
    include "applicationSettings.cfm";
}
```

Comment: Why require url.reinit to be a boolean - I generally just check it exists in the URL and leave it at that? I used to check true/false but I think only as a habit from Fusebox days... don't see a point to it now?  (Of course, on a public server there's benefit to checking against a specific password for re-initing, to avoid potential appreload-based DoSing.)

Comment: Good point @PeterBoughton: force of habit. It's not like the thing is ever gonna be passed as "false" and for there to be a legitimate action to take if so ;-) (code updated)

Comment: When I push a site to production, I tend to set reinit to a value that cannot be easily guessed so that others cannot reinit the app. Why am I worried about that? I do not know. @AdamCameron - in my apps, I frequently have code that checks for value of 'reinit' in `onrequestStart()` that simplt calls `onApplicationStart()`. Not sure why you were implying this could not be done.

Comment: @ScottStroz where did I imply that, mate? What I said was running an event handler is not the same as the actual event occurring. Running `onApplicationStart()` does not - in and off itself - start the application, it merely reruns that code. The `onClick()` / mouse-button analogy is an easy way to understand it what I mean: running `onclick()` does NOT make the mouse button depress. That said, often when people say they want to restart their app, they *actually* mean they want to *reinitialise* their app, which is a different thing, and is acheived by rerunning `onApplicationStart()`.

Comment: @ScottStroz: good point re securing that URL better. We require both the `reinit` param to be passed, plus a password, plus - actually - has to be run from a specific - access-controlled - domain for it to work. Why? Belt & braces perhaps, but equally we have past employees which might want to be mischievous, and this saves them from that temptation.

Comment: @AdamCameron - I guess I misunderstood your meaning. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

In OnRequestStart() put something like this:

```
param name='url.reloadApp' default='no';

if(url.reloadApp == 'yes')
{
    applicationStop();
}
```